# How to get the typescript compiler to find bokeh's "*d.ts" files

Tags: javascript, typescript, bokeh, tsconfig

I have recently moved from Bokeh's nice, inline extension framework to [their npm based *out of line* build system](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html#pre-built-extensions), I am trying go get my extension to build, but Bokeh installs all of the TypeScript `*.ts.d` in a separate tree, for example:

```
bash$ find node_modules -name 'serialization.*'
node_modules/@bokeh/bokehjs/build/js/types/core/util/serialization.d.ts
node_modules/@bokeh/bokehjs/build/js/lib/core/util/serialization.js
bash$
```

In the *inline build system* this file is imported like `import { is_NDArray_ref, decode_NDArray } from "core/util/serialization"`.

Is there a way using `tsconfig.json` options to allow my extension files to continue to use `core/util/serialization` for import **and** find both the JavaScript and the TypeScript description with Bokeh's node installation layout.

The only dependency in my `package.json` is:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@bokeh/bokehjs": "^2.3.1"
  },
```

Even if I change the import paths to use `.../lib/...`, TypeScript does not find the `*.d.ts` files, and if I change the import path to use `.../types/...` if finds the types and compiles but the linker fails to find the JavaScript. I used Bokeh's `bokeh init` to create my build sandbox... Thanks for any advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in a [Bokeh ticket](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/10055). In a nutshell, adding:

```
"paths": {
  "@bokehjs/*": [
    "./node_modules/@bokeh/bokehjs/build/js/lib/*",
    "./node_modules/@bokeh/bokehjs/build/js/types/*"
  ]
}
```

to the `tsconfig.json` file in the `compilerOptions` property allows imports like:

```
import { is_NDArray_ref, decode_NDArray } from "@bokehjs/core/util/serialization"
```

which seems very reasonable.